# Exclude Database from Streaming Replication

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

Is it possible to exclude a specific database from streaming replication in Pg 9.1?

Say I have two databases A and B defined, the goal is to ignore everything concerning database B on the backup server.

Thanks for your hints!

Comment: Have you found any solution to your requirement? I am facing the same issue with psql 9.5, any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible. The replication always works for the complete cluster.

With Postgres 9.5 or later you can use the extension [pglogical](https://2ndquadrant.com/en/resources/pglogical/) to do that.

Comment: with psql 9.5 is it possible to exclude some database as well as exclude some tables from one db from streaming the data between master and slave? I am planning to follow this link, https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/postgresql-replication-on-ubuntu-15-04/ any suggestion?

Comment: @Devang: no, it's not. The only way to do that with Postgres 9.5 would be to use the `pglocical` extension: https://2ndquadrant.com/en/resources/pglogical/  (note that `psql` is the name of the command line client. A short name for the DBMS is either Postgres or pgsql)

Comment: no experience with pglocical; if you got some idea about, is this legit, opensource, robust, ready to use in production?

Comment: Yeah Gone through to it, after digging little found these tools as well, bucardo https://bucardo.org/wiki/Main_Page, pgpool-II http://www.pgpool.net/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page which could be at use for my requirement; do you have any experince to share regarding the comparision to these tool?

Comment: after sorting out, i can use either bucardo or pglogical, any suggestion which one should i use?

Comment: If you are using a newer pg versions, logical replication may be a choice https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/logical-replication.html

Answer (score 2):

Use `Slony-I` http://slony.info/ or other replication solutions to replicate partially.